# How to resize an image in relative to another image using numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to blend two images, but I have a problem with making the size of both images the same. The following link has code that I used as reference:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/05/image-processing-using-numpy-with-practical-implementation-and-code/

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
image=plt.imread('image.jpeg')
image0 = plt.imread('imaage1.jpeg')
resized=ndarray(image0).resize(image.shape[1::-1])
plt.imshow(resized)
print(('shape: '),resized.shape)
print(('dtype : '),image0.dtype)
dst = (image * 0.6 + image0 * 0.4)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(dst)
```

This is the code I have tried and I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "G:\Python\image pro using numpy.py", line 56, in <module>
    plt.imshow(resized)

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2903, in imshow
    __ret = gca().imshow(

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1361, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5609, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)

  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 700, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data of dtype {} cannot be converted to "

TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Comment: `image.resize()` is an in-place operation and returns `None`, as you can easily check. You still work with `image0` afterward. Given the subsequent operations, you probably mean `image0.resize(image.shape)`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to open the image using PIL: `from PIL import Image`

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img = np.array(Image.open('img.jpg'))
img0 = np.array(Image.open('img0.jpg').resize(img.shape[1::-1]))
dst = (img * 0.6 + img0 * 0.4).astype(np.uint8)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(dst)
```